# Getting an OAuth2 authentication token in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get an OAuth token using a ClientID and SecretID.

My code so far:

```
    Dim clientId As String = "8cd6b80dd822961f362"
    Dim clientSecret As String = "5afbd4bb280f29cba5ec1f362"
    Dim credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret)
    Dim headerValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials))

    Dim content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
                                            {"client_id", clientId},
                                            {"client_secret", clientSecret},
                                            {"response_type", "code"},
                                            {"redirect_uri", "https://somesite.com/"},
                                            {"grant_type", "authorization_code"}})
    Dim requestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.site.com/oauth2/authorize")
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headerValue)
    requestMessage.Content = content

    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    Dim task = client.SendAsync(requestMessage)
    Dim response = task.Result
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
    Dim responseBody As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    MsgBox(responseBody)
```

The above code returns the HTML for the redirect_uri site and not a token.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Using Postman and the credentials provided I managed to get the token.

Comment: Could you perform a network trace from postman of a successful authentication and share the different requests with redirections and status codes? Could you please add the point where your VB process stops, too?

Comment: When I use Postman to get a token, it opens a browser window and prompts me to select a certificate from the store before continuing. How can I replicate this in my code? I think this is the part I'm missing: selecting a certificate to send along with the request.

Comment: Are you using something like a smart card reader or where is the certificate stored?

Comment: I have a digital signature USB token with a certificate installed.

Answer (score 0):

By default `HttpClient` is using `AllowAutoRedirect = true`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-7.0) says:

> The Authorization header is cleared on auto-redirects and the handler automatically tries to re-authenticate to the redirected location. No other headers are cleared. In practice, this means that an application can't put custom authentication information into the Authorization header if it is possible to encounter redirection.

So depending on the setup of the server you might have to create a `CookieContainer` and do the redirecting on your own.

**Update:**

The usage of a certificate store is something I didn't get from your question. If you want to do similar handling of certificates like browsers do you have to implement this feature yourself. Here is a C# example of how you can extend `WebClient` class with a dedicated `CookieContainer` and `X509` certificate handling. I used it with smart card reader. It should work similar in vb.net. Hope it helps to find the right .Net classes and how to put things together:

```cs
public class SmartCardClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    public Uri LastResponseUri = null;
    public X509Certificate2 cert = null;
    private string IssuerName = null;

    public SmartCardClient(string issuerName)
    {
        IssuerName = issuerName;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        SelectCertificate();
    }
            
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        LastResponseUri = null;
        
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        }

        return request;
    }
    
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        LastResponseUri = response.ResponseUri;
        return response;
    }
    
    public void SelectCertificate()
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection certs = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates
            .Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false)
            .Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false)
            .Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, IssuerName, false);

        if (certs.Count > 1)
            certs = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
                certs, "Select Certificate", "Please select a certificate:",
                X509SelectionFlag.MultiSelection
            );
            
        if (certs.Count > 0)
            cert = certs[0];

        store.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use Postman to get a token, it opens a browser window and prompts me to select a certificate from the store before continuing. How can I replicate this in my code? I think this is the part I'm missing: selecting a certificate to send along with the request.

Comment: @milo2011 I've added c# example code that I used for authentication via a smart card reader. Hope it gives some general hints how you can handle cookies and certificates.

Answer (score 0):

The second step of a code flow uses the token endpoint, not the authorize endpoint. Your payload looks correct though. Try posting it to this endpoint:

```
https://api.site.com/oauth2/token
```

Comment: When I use Postman to get a token, it opens a browser window and prompts me to select a certificate from the store before continuing. How can I replicate this in my code? I think this is the part I'm missing: selecting a certificate to send along with the request.

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense. Your code is running the second step of a code flow (user login), and these never use client certificates. Please take some time to update your question in terms of your use case, components involved, and requirements instead of just technology. Feel free to include desired behaviour when using Postman.